# how to merge next line to current line by keeping the next line

Tags: awk, sed, vi

I have this:

```
A abc
B abc
C abc
D abc
...
```

and I need to have such file output:

```
A abc B abc
B abc C abc
C abc D abc
D abc ..
...
```

I tried this:
`sed 'N;s/\n/ /'` but this removes the next line.

Answer (score 6):

With `sed`:

```
sed '1{h;$p;d;};H;x;s/\n/ /;$G' file
```

On reading the first line; the line is stored into hold space (**h**). If it is also the last line (a file consisting of one line only) then it will be printed out (**$p**). Otherwise, it won't be printed. Then the pattern space is deleted and next cycle is started (**d**).

On each subsequent line: a newline character and the line just read is appended to the hold space (**H**), then hold and pattern spaces are exchanged (**x**). The newline character is replaced with a space (**s/\n/ /**). If it is the last line, the line just read will be appended to the current pattern space with a leading newline (**$G**).

Comment: A short explanation what this does would improve the answer.

Comment: @KlausGütter I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, written based on shown samples. Written and tested it in https://ideone.com/6BGYTy

```
awk 'prev{print prev,$0} {prev=$0}' Input_file
```

OR in case you want to print last line then try:

```
awk 'prev{print prev,$0} {prev=$0} END{print}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** simply checking condition if prev is not null then print prev and current line. Then setting prev's value to current line. So in very first line it wouldn't print anything but from 2nd line onwards it will print lines as per OP's shown samples.

Comment: You could add `END{print}`.

Comment: @Cyrus, sure added it now, I thought OP didn't need it, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

With `paste`, `sed` and `bash` (Process Substitution):

```
paste -d " " file <(sed 1d file)
```

Output:

```
A abc B abc
B abc C abc
C abc D abc
D abc ...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/\n\(.*\)/ \1&/;P;D' file
```

Append the next line and using pattern matching, insert that line (replacing the newline by a space) before the appended line.

The `P`and `D` commands will print the first of the two lines and then delete it, leaving the second line intact, ready for the next line to be appended etc.

N.B. This will print an unpaired last line, to only print paired lines use:

```
sed 'N;s/\n\(.*\)/ \1&/;P;$d;D' file
```

An alternative unpaired/paired solution:

```
sed -Ez 's/\n(\S+)/ \1&/g' file
```

or:

```
sed -Ez 's/\n(\S+)/ \1&/g;s/[^\n]*\n$//' file
```

Answer (score 2):

When the input is from a stream (not a file), you can change the solution of @Cyrus into

```
some_program | sed '2,$ s/.*/&\n&/' | paste -d" " - -
```

When some_program is running a long time, you will have to wait before seeing the results.

Answer (score 1):

An improvement on [*Cyrus*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63643561/6136214), but with `tail`, (instead of `sed`), and plain `sh`:

```
tail -n +2 file | paste -d " " file -
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the file itself, you can script `ed`:

```sh
ed -s input.txt <<'EOF'
1,$-1g/^/s/$/ /\
.+1t.\
.-1,.j
w
EOF
```

For each line but the last: add a space to the end, make a copy of the next line, and join the original line and that copy into a single line. Finally save the file.

Answer (score 0):

In **vi** you can write a macro to do this.

1. Open file in vi.
2. Then type the following keystrokes

   `ggqajYkpkJ0jq`

Commentary

```
gg  # Go to Line 1 column 1
qa  # Begin recording macro a.
j   # Go to next line
Y   # Yank this line into buffer
k   # return to previous line
p   # Paste buffer below current line
k   # return to previous line
J   # Join line below cursor to current line
0   # Return to col 1 of current line
j   # go to next line
q   # Stop recording the macro
```

Your cursor should now be on Line 2 column 1.

You're now ready to execute your macro.

You've already completed line 1.

To run on remainder of file enter N-1@a where N=Number of lines in files.

If file has 100 lines enter `99@a` to run macro on remaining 99 lines.